Which attributes to underline if a primary key is made out of a composite attribute in an ER-Diagram?
Let's say an entitity has a composite attribute "name" which is made out of "first name" and "last name".
If "name" is the primary key, should I underline only "name", or "first name" and "last name" as well?
Thank you!

The ERD notation requires to underline all the components of a primary key, if it is a composite key, so first name and last name would both be underlined.
Not related: first name and last name are not good candidates for a primary key, since the combination is not sufficiently distinctive to be unique and there would be no way to distinguish to different persons sharing the same combination. There are for example more than 600 persons named Adam Smith alone in New York.
